# Notification error: Adding notification request failed with error

Tags: ios, notifications, nsmanagedobjectid

Attempting to create a local notification fails with the following error:

```
Adding notification request failed with error: Error
Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named
com.apple.usernotifications.usernotificationservice" UserInfo=
{NSDebugDescription=connection to service named 
com.apple.usernotifications.usernotificationservice}
```

What does that mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is caused by attempting to pass a URL from `objectID.uriRepresentation()` in `userInfo` of the notification.

It is necessary to store `objectID.uriRepresentation().absoluteString` instead.

When the notification is handled, the `objectID` can be recovered by:

```
persistentStoreCoordinator
    .managedObjectID(forURIRepresentation: URL(string: uri))
```

Comment: Thanks. Got the same error message, and following your answer, I found out that I was setting a non-property list type in the notification's `UserInfo`. I have removed it and it started to work :)

Answer (score 2):

I got this by including a `NSUUID`/`UUID` in a dictionary, switching to the string representation has stopped the error being reported!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the issue by trying to add userInfo with a URL type value. Fixed by changed the `URL` to `String`.

You may check whether your input value is String Value. If not, make it as a string could fix this issue.